# Fluency movement of the square with a mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How to make a fluency movement of the square with the help of `CSS` when clicking the mouse. It is only necessary to move fluency , then the square goes beyond the rectangle, the task is not important.

```js
let cube = document.querySelector('[id="cube"]');
let field = document.querySelector('[id="field"]');

field.onclick = function(event) {
  cube.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
  cube.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
}
```

```css
#field {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZfIPM5SZT9qpWY2xZAx3FQ.png" id="cube">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inserting the code below into the CSS style for the `#cube`

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s; 
-moz-transition: all 1s; 
-o-transition: all 1s; 
-ms-transition: all 1s; 
transition: all 1s;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *transition* - see demo below when I added something like `transition: all 1s linear;` or it can be more *specific* like:

`transition: top 1s linear, left 1s linear`

You can check out the *timing functions* and use as appropriate.

See demo below using *ease*:

```js
let cube = document.querySelector('[id="cube"]');
let field = document.querySelector('[id="field"]');

field.onclick = function(event) {
  cube.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
  cube.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
}
```

```css
#field {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: top 1s ease, left 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZfIPM5SZT9qpWY2xZAx3FQ.png" id="cube">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible by adding `transition:all .2s ease;` to the cube's CSS.

```js
let cube=document.querySelector('[id="cube"]');
let field=document.querySelector('[id="field"]');

field.onclick=function(event) {
  cube.style.left=event.clientX + 'px';
  cube.style.top=event.clientY + 'px';      
}
```

```css
#field {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 10px groove black;

      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
}
#cube {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease; 
-moz-transition: all .2s ease; 
-o-transition: all .2s ease; 
-ms-transition: all .2s ease; 
transition:all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="field"> 
  <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZfIPM5SZT9qpWY2xZAx3FQ.png" id="cube"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
let cube = document.querySelector('[id="cube"]');
let field = document.querySelector('[id="field"]');

field.onclick = function(event) {
  cube.style.transform = "translate(" + event.clientX + "px, " + event.clientY + "px)";
  cube.style['-webkit-transform'] = "translate(" + event.clientX + "px, " + event.clientY + "px)";
}
```

```css
#field {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cube {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: top left;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top left;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZfIPM5SZT9qpWY2xZAx3FQ.png" id="cube">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I would not use the all as maybe other elements will require different parameters.

My sample misses the others browsers support, so add code for them as well:
`-moz-transition` `-o-transition` `-ms-transition`